# SPFarm.Local Object Being Cached in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2010, 2013, solution-deployment, solution, ssom

I am experiencing an odd issue where the SPFarm.Local object is not being updated for SharePoint 2013, but it does for 2010.  Basically I have some code that adds/deploys/updates SharePoint solutions in C#.  I have the thread wait until the solution is added and/or the deployment job is complete before continuing.

This is a simplified version of the code:

```
var complete = false;
while (!complete)
{
    complete = SPFarm.Local.Solutions[“solutionName.wsp”] != null;
    if (!complete)
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

In SharePoint 2010, this works perfectly.  However, in 2013 the solution is continually returning null.  I can verify the solution exists in a separate PowerShell window with Get-SPSolution, but it is not updating in this thread.

Any ideas on how to get SharePoint 2013 to update the SPFarm.Local object in the main thread?

Comment: how are you adding the solution? also see this thread: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42927/programmatically-deploy-to-site-collection-level-using-c

Comment: SPFarm.Local.Solutions.Add(path).  This behavior also occurs when waiting for a solution to deploy (for the JobExists property to no longer be "true").  Something about 2013 is making the SPFarm.Local object not update.

Comment: I wonder if `SPFarm.Update()` afterwards would make a difference?

Comment: Trying that now. Will keep you posted.

Comment: That worked! Before making the thread sleep, I am updating the SPFarm. It works perfectly. Put that in an answer so I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SP.Update()` should work after you add the solution to the farm.

```
var complete = false;
while (!complete)
{
    complete = SPFarm.Local.Solutions[“solutionName.wsp”] != null;
    if (!complete){
        SPFarm.Local.Update();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
       }
}
```